# Load image synchronously with glide and cache it in the disk

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm doing something like this to get bitmap synchronously and set it as image by using imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

```
return Glide
    .with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(width, height)
    .get();
```

I need to do it synchronously because I'm doing it inside AsyncTask's doInBackground. I need to fetch image url from the backend before loading it with glide.  Later I'm loading the same url into view directly with glide.
The problem is that image is not cached in the disk.  Any solution for this?

Comment: caching only works when you remain on same page

Answer (score 1):

Use `diskCacheStrategy`

```
return Glide
    .with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .asBitmap()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(width, height)
    .get();
```

Comment: Hi Reaz, diskCacheStrategy  returns DrawableRequestBuilder, so you no longer can use .asBitmap()

Comment: Updated the answer. Did you try moving         `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` under `asBitmap()` function?

Comment: yes I tries that, for some reason images are not cached anyway. On the next screen I do             Glide.with(this).load(mArticle.getImgLink()).into(imageHeader); And it starts to load image again.

Comment: So put the `diskCacheStrategy` there.

Comment: How did you know that doesn't help? Can you detect if it gets the image from server?

Comment: Yes it's very slow server, so I'm sure. I'm not new to glide and I spent 2 days trying to solve this issue. I know your solution for years, it works when I load image directly into imageview, but when I use .get() it don't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

add `diskCacheStrategy` to your Glide, Select StrategyType as **Source**

You can have idea why to use SOURCE from this [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/281)

`DiskCacheStrategy.NONE` caches nothing, as discussed

`DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE` caches only the original full-resolution image.

`DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT` caches only the final image, after reducing the resolution (and possibly transformations) (default behavior)

`DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` caches all versions of the image

try:
to get Bitmap From URL:

```
return Glide
    .with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .asBitmap()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    .into(width, height)
    .get();
```

For loading in ImageView :

```
       Glide
        .with(mContext)
        .load(url)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
        .into(imageView) // your ImageViewID here
```

For loading Image into ImageView after getting Bitmap:

```
   Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .asBitmap()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                iv_image.setImageBitmap(resource); // you can store resource to some variable too if you want to update more than 1 images or try it like iv_image2.setImageBitmap(resource)
                iv_image.requestLayout();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried that, the same result as DiskCacheStrategy.ALL

Comment: you have to use the DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE wherever you are loading image. It will do the caching for sure. Its not like you write at one place so you will get the result, specify the same at all occurrences.

Comment: I did that believe me, it loads again. Did you try this code?

Comment: Hold on, you want to get the bitmap from URL or want to load it directly in imageview? also check link in my answer

Comment: I want to fetch image url in a new thread and load it into imageview, if I call glide onPostExecute it's a concurrency nightmare. And I'm not new to glide and I spent 2 days trying to solve this issue. I know your solution for years, it works when I load image directly into imageview, but when I use .get() it don't do anything.

Comment: Actually for me both these codes are working, Just checked. Also updated answer a bit

Comment: hmm, did you use .get() inside doInBackground?

Comment: Yes, but i think you should try the third snippet if it fits your requirements

Comment: As I told you I'm not a novice, so no need to write basics of glide. And it's interesting how you think I can use the third snippet in doInBackground? I wrote very specific question, if you can answer it I will be very happy and thankful, otherwise please stop wasting my time with random stuff.

Comment: It's magic that it works for you, but not for me with .get(), so please if it's true write the complete solution with asynctask and .get() which caches images

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue many times the best way to overcome it is by using interfaces to load data after it is fetched inside glide **CustomTarget**

Create a new file called OnglideLoaded.java file like this:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public interface OnGlideLoaded {
    void onGlideLoaded(Drawable drawable);
}
```

Now create setter method for it like this where glide is:

```
public void setOnGlideLoaded(OnGlideLoaded onGlideLoaded) {
    this.onGlideLoaded = onGlideLoaded;
}
```

Not call it inside Glide Target:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .asBitmap()
     .load(uri)
     .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
           @Override
           public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                 icon = resource;
                 if (onGlideLoaded!=null){
                        //This will send the image to every registered interface
                        onGlideLoaded.onGlideLoaded(icon);
                 }
           }

           @Override
           public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

           }
});
```

Now call the interface like this where you want the image:

```
reference.setOnGlideLoaded(new OnGlideLoaded() {
    @Override
    public void onGlideLoaded(Drawable drawable) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(drawable);
    }
});
```

> Here, reference will be the object where you created the setter method.